# TypeError: state.products.find is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import { ActionType } from "../costants/action-type";

const initialState = {
    products : [],
}


export const productReducer = (state = initialState, {type,payload}) => {

    console.log("DEC",payload)
    console.log("state",state.products)

    switch (type) {
        case ActionType.SET_PRODUCTS:
            return {state , 
                products: [...state.products.find(product => product.API === payload.API)],
            };
            default:
                return state;
            }
        }
```

[The screenshot for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDcvX.png)

Comment: Hi. The way you are updating state in ActionType.SET_PRODUCTS is incorrect. You need to spread the state instead of passing it directly. Secondly, `products` is an array. And, find returns a single entry from the array. So, you are trying to spread single product in the array. Please revisit your logic in this line. I think you are looking to filter the data. So, replace `find` with `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map` (returns a list) instead of `find` (returns a single object).

And you should assign state like `{...state }` to keep all current state values as well.

```js
import { ActionType } from "../costants/action-type";

const initialState = {
    products : [],
}


export const productReducer = (state = initialState, {type,payload}) => {

    console.log("DEC",payload)
    console.log("state",state.products)

    switch (type) {
        case ActionType.SET_PRODUCTS:
            return {
                ...state, 
                products: [...state.products.map(product => product.API === payload.API)],
            };
            default:
                return state;
            }
        }
```